# Sqoop: --as-parquetfile is not working

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

i want save sqoop files as parquet file directly to hdfs. i am trying below command to do so. but facing  `ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException`

sqoop version - 1.4.7

> sqoop import --options-file /home/user/optionsfile.txt --query "select
>   * from table where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir 'hdfs:///user/x/sqoop1' --as-parquetfile -m 1;

when i try same sqoop command without `--as-parquetfile` job is executing successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an open bug in sqoop i would like you to suggest that first import the data into a temporary hive table in text format and then insert into another hive table which is in parquete format.

Comment: What if I am not using hive, required is to fetch a table from postgres to hdfs in parquet format.
Query runs good without (--as-parquetfie) which gives error of unrecognized argument with parquet option. Please help.

Comment: See doesn't matter you won't be able to fetch data using the --as-parquetfile tool as it is not working. As far as I understand your use-case, pull the file in a supported file format (ORC or CSV or AVRO) to HDFS and then use HIVE or PIG or SPARK to read and then convert it into parquet format. That is the only option I see with the information you provided.

Also, I think this bug should have been resolved in future releases, try using a newer version of SQOOP or maybe use a Spark code, no one uses SQOOP nowadays, it is too old and runs on MAP-REDUCE. Go with Spark if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `--table` instead of using `--query`and check.

There is a open bug SQOOP-2571 for this issue.

Comment: i need to use query to overcome unwanted data from source. any workaround for query ?

Comment: **@Kaleby Jaun** has [recommended](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/199753/view.html) the same *workaround*, albeit for a *slightly* different error (which is still related to `--as-parquetfile` option)